# switchIfEmpty does not emit vales from second observable if first one is empty

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using `switchIfEmpty` operator in RxJava to use a secondary observable when the primary observable doesn't have a value. Following is my code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      getFirstObservable()
        .switchIfEmpty { getSecondObservable() }
        .subscribe { println(it) }
}

fun getFirstObservable() = Observable.empty<String>()
fun getSecondObservable() = Observable.just("String1", "String2")
```

However, even if the first observable is empty, it never emits values from the second observable, and nothing is printed in the output. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use normal parenthesis, not curly braces. It's a pretty common mistake with Kotlin when you need to provide an argument, not a lambda.

Comment: @akarnokd This is the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use normal parenthesis, not curly braces. It's a pretty common mistake with Kotlin when you need to provide an argument, not a lambda.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    getFirstObservable()
        // ----------- v --------------------- v --------------
        .switchIfEmpty ( getSecondObservable() )
        // ----------- ^ --------------------- ^ --------------
        .subscribe { println(it) }
}

fun getFirstObservable() = Observable.empty<String>()
fun getSecondObservable() = Observable.just("String1", "String2")
```